# How to transform a List of a List of dicts into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I Have have an output from a web crawling and I don't know how to convert into a Pandas Dataframe.

This is my output:

```
[[{'galaxy s10': 1, 'galaxy m30': 1, 'iphone xs max': 1, 'one vision': 1, 'moto g7': 1}], [{'iphone 11': 3}], [], [], [{'iphone 11': 1}, {'iphone 11': 1}]]
```

I think this output is a list of a lists of `dicts`.

I would like to transform into a pandas dataframe, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/993TV.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves the problem.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
a_list = [[{'galaxy s10': 1, 'galaxy m30': 1, 'iphone xs max': 1, 'one vision': 1, 'moto g7': 1}],
          [{'iphone 11': 3}], [], [], [{'iphone 11': 1}, {'iphone 11': 1}]]
consolidate = []
for l in list(chain(*a_list)):
    temp = {}
    for k,(key, value) in enumerate(l.items()) :
        temp.update({f"Cellphone{k+1}":key,
                     f"Cellphone{k+1}_views":value})
    consolidate.append(temp)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(consolidate)
df
```

The output:
[image]

this part `list(chain(*a_list ))` will transform the list of lists.